# Java different generic bounds extending the same class

Tags: java

What is a reason behind class generic declaration and method generic argument `E extends MyError` are not considered to have the same bound?

```
class Err<T, E extends MyError> {
    private E error;

    public <newT, newE extends MyError> Err<newT, newE> doSomething() {
        return new Err<newT, newE>(error);
    }
}
```

IntelliJ says `Required type:newE, Provided:E`

Isn't both `E` and `newE` have the same bounds so they should be interchangeable? Meaning `newE` return type extends `MyError` and E also extends `MyError`, so why can't I use error value if both `E` and `newE` bounds are the same (e.g. extends MyError)?

How can I keep this `X extends Y` dynamic behavior so that everything that satisfies `extends MyError` can be used to instantiate `Err` class?

Comment: You've defined `Err` as being generic on types `T` and `E`. **Why** are you adding `newT` and `newE`? The problem is `E error` is not a `newE`.

Comment: Because `E` could be `MyCoolError` (`extends MyErrror`) and `newE` could be `MyEvenCoolerError` (`extends MyError`), but `MyEvenCoolerError` is not assignable to `MyCoolError` and vice versa

Comment: "*Isn't both `E` and `newE` have the same bounds so they should be interchangeable?*" - No, that's where it falls apart. `E` and `newE` could still be of different types, just as @knittl mentioned. For the same reason you can't interchange `String` and `Integer`, even though they both extend `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler (or IntelliJ) says that because the type parameters `E` and `newE` are completely separate type parameters.

Note that the field `error` is of type `E`, and inside your method you are treating it as if it is of type `newE` - you get an error because those are not the same types.

Why did you declare the type parameters `newT` and `newE` on the method? You could just use the `T` and `E` that were declared on the class:

```
class Err<T, E extends MyError> {
    private E error;

    Err(E error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public Err<T, E> doSomething() {
        return new Err<>(error);
    }
}
```

(Note: class `Err` in your example is also missing a constructor).

Answer (score 1):

It would have the same bound if it was defined as the following

```
public class Err<T, E extends MyError> {
    private final E error;

    Err(E error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public  Err<T, E> doSomething() {
        return new Err<>(error);
    }
}
```